# Backbone view doesn't render template passed to it

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I need to be able to pass different template IDs to different routes.

```
(function() {
    window.App = {
        Models: {},
        Collections: {},
        Views: {},
        Router: {}
    };

    var vent = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);

    _.templateSettings.interpolate = /\[\[(.+?)\]\]/g;

    App.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            '' : 'index',
            'send-message' : 'sendMessage',
            '*other' : 'other'
        },
        index: function() {
            t = new (App.Collections.Tables.extend({ url: 'main-contact'}))();
            tables = App.Views.Tables({ collection: t, template: 'mainContactTemplate' });
            $('#web-leads').html(tables.el);
        },
        sendMessage: function() {
            // t = new (App.Collections.Tables.extend({ url: 'send-message'}))();
            // tables = new App.Views.Tables.extend({ collection: t, template: template('sendMessageTemplate')});
            // $('#web-leads').html(tables.el);
        },
        other: function() {

        }
    });

    // Main Contact
    App.Models.Table = Backbone.Model.extend({});

    App.Collections.Tables = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: App.Models.Table,
        initialize: function(models, options) {
            this.fetch({
                success: function(data) {
                    //console.log(data.models);
                }
            });
            if (options) {
                this.url = this.url || options.url;
            }
        }
    });

    App.Views.Tables = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'ul',
        initialize: function() {
            this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this);
        },
        render: function() {
            return this.collection.each(this.addOne, this);
        },
        addOne: function(model) {
            var t = new App.Views.Table({ model: model});
            this.$el.append(t.render().el);
            return this;
        }
    });

    App.Views.Table = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'li',
        initialize: function(options) {
            this.template = options.template;
            console.log(this.options);
        },
        retrieveTemplate: function(model) {
            return _.template($('#' + this.template).html(), model);
        },
        render: function() {
            this.$el.html(this.retrieveTemplate(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        }
    });

    new App.Router();
    Backbone.history.start();
})();
```

But I get an error than `n is undefined`.  I think I need to pass `this.template` into my `retrieveTemplate` function.  But shouldn't it already be set?  This code works, by the way, if I  hard code in the name of the template ID in the `retrieveTemplate` function.

EDIT:  the template isn't being passed from the call in the router.  That's where this is breaking down.

EDIT:  I took out the call to extend in the second line of the index route and now I get `this._configure is not a function`

WORKING VERSION:

```
(function() {
    window.App = {
        Models: {},
        Collections: {},
        Views: {},
        Router: {}
    };

    var vent = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);

    _.templateSettings.interpolate = /\[\[(.+?)\]\]/g;

    App.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            '' : 'index',
            'send-message' : 'sendMessage',
            '*other' : 'other'
        },
        index: function() {
            var t = new (App.Collections.Tables.extend({ url: 'main-contact'}))();
            var tables = new (App.Views.Tables.extend({ collection: t, options: {template: 'mainContactTemplate' }}))();
            $('#web-leads').html(tables.render().el);
        },
        sendMessage: function() {
            // t = new (App.Collections.Tables.extend({ url: 'send-message'}))();
            // tables = new App.Views.Tables.extend({ collection: t, template: template('sendMessageTemplate')});
            // $('#web-leads').html(tables.el);
        },
        other: function() {

        }
    });

    // Main Contact
    App.Models.Table = Backbone.Model.extend({});

    App.Collections.Tables = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: App.Models.Table,
        initialize: function(models, options) {
            this.fetch({
                success: function(data) {
                    //console.log(data.models);
                }
            });
            if (options) {
                this.url = this.url || options.url;
            }
        }
    });

    App.Views.Tables = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'ul',
        initialize: function(options) {
            this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this);
            this.template = this.options.template;
        },
        render: function() {
            this.collection.each(this.addOne, this);
            return this;
        },
        addOne: function(model, options) {
            //console.log(model);
            var t = new App.Views.Table({ model: model, template: this.options.template});
            this.$el.append(t.render().el);
            return this;
        }
    });

    App.Views.Table = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'li',
        initialize: function(options) {
            //console.log(this.options);
            this.template = this.options.template;
        },
        retrieveTemplate: function(model) {
            return _.template($('#' + this.template).html(), model);
        },
        render: function() {
            //console.log(this);
            this.$el.html(this.retrieveTemplate(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        }
    });

    new App.Router();
    Backbone.history.start();
})();
```

Comment: Why are you doing `Tables = App.Views.Tables.extend();`?

Comment: So I can pass something other than the collection.  Is that wrong?

Comment: I think we need a functional but minimal demo of the problem, there seem to be things going on that we can't see.

Comment: I'll post the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your router says this:

```
tables = App.Views.Tables({ collection: t, template: 'mainContactTemplate' });
```

So you're giving a `template: '...'` to `App.Views.Tables`. The `initialize` in `App.Views.Tables` looks like this:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this);
}
```

so it ignores the `template` option. If we look at `App.Views.Table` (singular!), we see this:

```
initialize: function(options) {
    this.template = options.template;
    console.log(this.options);
}
```

but `App.Views.Table` is instantiated without a `template` option:

```
var t = new App.Views.Table({ model: model});
```

You need to fix how you use `App.Views.Table`. Backbone will put a [view's constructor options in `this.options` for you](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor) so you just need to say:

```
var t = new App.Views.Table({ model: model, template: this.options.template });
```

---

A couple other things to consider:

1. You have some accidental globals in your router's `index` method, you should have `var t` and `var tables` rather than just `t` and `tables`.
2. A view's `render` method conventionally returns `this` so that you can say `$x.append(v.render().el)` so you might want to adjust your `render` methods to match the convention.

Comment: I had to something completely different, but it works.  Take a look at what I did above and let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to bind the context. Underscore can help you with that.

[*.bindAll*](http://underscorejs.org/#bindAll) or [.bind](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) should do it.

I typically just use _.bindAll during initialization as shown below.

```
...
initialize: function(options) {
    _.bindAll(this); // apply appropriate context
    this.template = options.template;
},
...
```

Hope this helped, best of luck.

Comment: You're missing the new keyword before 
    tables = App.Views.Tables ...

you're never actually instantiating the view...

Also might want to add a var before t and tables to constrain their scope.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that after I posted.

Comment: But that didn't solve the problem.  The only thing that seems to make this run is to make the calls in the router self-invoking functions, but I'm told this is not the way to do things.  But without the self-invoking functions, the code doesn't run.

Comment: Ok, so you're are passing the template to the Tables object when Table expects it. I think that is the problem.

Comment: Good thought, but that didn't help.

Comment: Tables calls Table, as the ul attaches the lis recursively.

Comment: I think "mu is too short" elaborated what I was getting at in his answer. I would really check your p's and q's because it is the likely culprit.

Comment: Options aren't inherited like that. You actually need to pass the template option into Tables from your route object, then pass it along to your Table from Tables object.